# CalledProcessError while installing Tensorflow using Bazel

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, bazel

I am trying to install Tensorflow from source using Bazel on Raspberry pi. I am following the official documentation as given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). When I run the `./configure` in Tensorflow directory after completing all the steps written for Bazel, I get the following error

```
/home/cvit/bin/bazel: line 88: /home/cvit/.bazel/bin/bazel-real: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/home/cvit/bin/bazel: line 88: /home/cvit/.bazel/bin/bazel-real: Success
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure.py", line 1552, in <module>
    main()
  File "./configure.py", line 1432, in main
    check_bazel_version('0.15.0')
  File "./configure.py", line 450, in check_bazel_version
    curr_version = run_shell(['bazel', '--batch', '--bazelrc=/dev/null', 'version'])
  File "./configure.py", line 141, in run_shell
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 223, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bazel', '--batch', '--bazelrc=/dev/null', 'version']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I didn't put the user flag in the bazel installation. So, I think this might be bazelrc error so I tried to set `$PATH=$BAZEL/bin` but nothing happened.

Please give any suggestion !!

Answer (score 4):

Probably the problem is that the non appropriate version of bazel is installed.
Run `bazel version` in the tensorflow directory, and see if there is an error.
If there is a problem with bazel version, then check out the .baselversion file, and if it contains a version that isn't installable with apt, then dowload the installer from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases then install it, else install with apt.
After that everything should work fine.